# What is the rc do inside the from random import choice as rc ? This is python

Tags: python

What does this mean `from random import choice as rc` especially the **rc** ?
I encountered this when browsing and trying to understand the way it works.

what does it do when I call `XXX.append(rc(XXX))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will import module into the program, so you can use functions included in the module.

```
import random
```

So you can print random character from the sequence as follows:

```
import random
print(random.choice('abcdefghij'))
```

Note that you must use the module name when calling the function choice.

Your code will import the function directly so you can call it by simple 'rc'

```
from random import choice as rc
print(rc('abcdefghij'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're new in Python, so here it goes:

`from random` tells python which library you want to import stuff from 
`import choice` tells python what module you want to import 
`as rc` set an alias to that module specified in the line above, which you can use to call that modulo BY its alias. For example: instead of calling `choice.something`, you will call `rc.something`

The documentation for this is here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0221/

Hope It helps

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially just giving your imported package/module a nickname. This is useful when you have multiple packages in the same namespace that share a name.

```
import random
random.choice()

# ------------------------------

from random import choice
choice()

# ------------------------------

from random import choice as xxxx
xxxx()
```

You can read more [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0221/)